# Dropdown text not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have been trying to implement a dropdown list in HTML. The dropdown is shown but the options inside the dropdown are not shown once selected.After selection, the box remains empty.

Following is the code -

```
<form action="evaluate">
  <select name="places">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" class="w3-button w3-red w3-margin-top" value="Submit">
</form>
```

`evaluate` is a servlet. I have to select an option from the dropdown. Then after clicking the submit button the data should go to the servlet named `evaluate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing was with the css files I was using. So, I had to change the class and do a little bit of styling as follows.

```
<div id ="drop" class="w3-content"">
<style>
#drop
{
background-color:black;
padding:0.9em;
}
</style><!-- code for dropdown menu--> </div>
```

Comment: It's bad rails form and really front end web development as a whole to have CSS definitions in HTML. You should think about refactoring that into a .css file.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra double quote! `<select name="places" ">` should `<select name="places">` and it works. See the following working link https://jsfiddle.net/xrvmjLpm/

Comment: Showing text where? In the fiddle it sends a json which is what the evaluate servlet should handle.

Comment: Text for the options shown in dropdown menu. Anyway, I solved the problem. There were some issues with the .css file. Thanks for your help though.